# Cannot filter on Column in some views of a doc library

Tags: 2010, list-view

I have a 2010 site that has a document library with a threshold of 7500 items. The library is currently sitting at over 8000 items, so we have created multiple views that filter on indexed columns.

[image: View filter Example]

Each of these views work and return an item amount under the threshold with most returning around 500 items. The issue is, that when I go to filter on a column in the view, I get the following error for only SOME of the views:

[image: Filter on Column Error]

I am pretty stumped on this one since there seems to be no consistency on when the error shows. For instance:

- View 'Starts with A' returns 538 items in 4 groups (Group By one indexed column), and it receives the error
- View 'Starts with T' returns 2262 items in 4 groups, and does not receive the error

I have compared the working views to the non-working views:

- CAML is the same (except for the filter criteria)
- View setup is the same (again, different filter criteria)

Also, there are no lookup fields in the library.

Any help/advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any chance the data is causing the issue? I have seen that happen. Maybe as a test, just limit the view to 10 to 15 items and see if it works.

Comment: @spevilgenius - Thanks for the advice. I tried that and I still get the same error.

Comment: Im still thinking it might be a data issue. However, is the filter the same as the "T" filter?

Comment: The filter on the view is the same format "Account Name begins with ... ", but it is T instead of A.

Comment: So, yes, to me this appears to be data related. If the filters are the same and the fields that are selected are the same, then it must be the data. I have seen this be the case but it is harder to find the cause. As long as the fields selected in the view are the same as the working ones. There are some fields that do not allow filtering to work.

Comment: Ended up removing the throttling on the list. Not ideal, but it works.